# Fresh installed ubuntu won't allow me to login

Tags: login

Installed ubuntu on my work laptop, everything worked great and I was in love with it. Said laptop is no longer operational, so today I installed it on my second, older laptop - and it won't let me login. After putting in the password I get a black screen after a few seconds, queue the typical drum sound and I get the login screen again with no errors. Same happens if I try to get in as guest. I've tried entering a wrong password and it's immediately recognised as being the wrong one. 
I tried logging in through ctrl+alt+f1, and it accepted the password. Tried changing password through there, changing xauthority ownership, and ultimately deleting it (as following possible solitions I found searching here). Nothing. Tried a fresh install after that, no luck still. I'm out of ideas as of right now, and would apreciate some help.

Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS, 64bit.

Toshiba Sattelite L650-1JT. 
 320gb hard drive memory, not sure on partition side since I didn't manually create any.
Graphic card ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470

Comment: did you allocate enough space for your file system?

Comment: Please update the post with laptop, Hard drive(gb), memory. The partition size of ubuntu (file system)

Comment: Make sure you have no broken packages "sudo dpkg --configure -a" "Sudo apt-get update" "sudo apt-get upgrade" "Sudo apt-get autoclean"

Comment: @DnrDevil Done. It spent some time upgrading, but problem is still there.

Comment: @DnrDevil Gave it another go with a fresh install. Gave me back an error related to "pixbuf module loader file" and "this likely means your instalation is broken". I followed the instructions it gave me but still, no changes. Does this mean I should redownload ubuntu?

Comment: Yes; make a new install disk. When completed install it while connected to wifi with 3rd partys

Comment: Did the instalation with a new install disk, but yet again  it didn't solve anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any useful data to help. However, in 8 cases of 10 this error comes from X malfunction, and in 6 of 10 - video adapter drivers. What video card you use?
Anyway, try pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 or F2 until you see a text login prompt. Log it. Then

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall 
reboot
```

Comment: I'm not too handy with computers, and rather new to ubuntu. So don't really know what info to give. Did what you sugested, problem still not solved.